# Possible to assign Azure Active Directory group users as VSTS stakeholders automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Can an AAD user group be assigned with "Stakeholder" permissions in Visual Studio Team Services "automatically"?

I can add an AAD group to VSTS, but when these users first log in to VSTS they are automatically granted "Basic" access by default. Is there a workaround to set "Stakeholder" as the default access level? This would allow me to more closely control the limited number of "Basic" seats available.

Ultimately, I want to use AAD groups to manage VSTS users and not have to adjust every single user account's VSTS permission levels individually.

from: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services

"Team Services automatically assigns them Basic features, if your account has seats available, or Stakeholder features, if not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn’t the way to set Stakeholder as the default access level and AAD user group can’t be assigned with Stakeholder level in VSTS.

Related article: Team Services: [Access with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) groups (Q&A)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-azure-active-directory-groups-visual-studio-team-services#qa)

> Q: How do I assign account access to Azure AD group members?
>
> A: When these group members sign in to your Team Services account for
>   the first time, Team Services assigns an access level to them
>   automatically. If they have Visual Studio subscriptions, Team Services
>   assigns the respective access level to them. Otherwise, Team Services
>   assigns them the next "best available" access level in this order:
>   Basic, Stakeholder.

On the other hand, access level is related to feature not permission, you need to specify the permission (add to corresponding group).

[Visual Studio Team Services Feature Comparison](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. More work for me to manage user access levels individually. Also our IT group was hoping to manage the access (and permissions) for VSTS through AAD groups.
Perhaps a separate question, but what happens to a VSTS user (pulled from AAD) when that user account is removed or deactivated in AAD (by our IT group, perhaps when a user leaves our company)?

Comment: You can't manage the access and permissions for VSTS through AAD groups. The user still can access your VSTS even though removed from AAD, you need to remove it from your VSTS, but if you disable (Block sign in) user in Azure, the user can't access your vsts any more.

Comment: That seems a bit confusing. You're saying that you can disable a user in AAD (Azure) to prevent access to VSTS, but removing a user in AAD does not prevent access to VSTS? I guess I will need to do some trial and error testing to confirm exactly what does happen when a user is disabled and/or removed via the federated AD user account.

Comment: I mean remove the user from AAD groups instead of remove a user from AAD (mistake in previous comment).